# Animation for Java

Tags: java, animation

I'm looking to find out more information on animation for Java,

Would be much appreciated if anyone can recommend any useful sites to learn more about this

Thanks,

Dawit

Comment: Hi, this is not the best site to get this kind of information, questions here should be specific about programming problems/questions.

Comment: don't use signature in question

Answer (score 1):

30 seconds Google search:

http://www.javaworld.com/jw-03-1996/jw-03-animation.html

http://www.developer.com/article.php/893471

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30419

Comment: The first two links don't work... (404)

Answer (score 1):

To learn Animation in Java start from [Java2D API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp) and [Java3D API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html)

Also See
[Java 2D API Sample Programs](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/samples/suite/)
[For examples and tutorials for Java 3D](http://www.java3d.org/)